# monte-carlo gone wrong

Tags: reference-request, random, monte-carlo

Can someone give examples where defective pseudo-random number generators gave incorrect simulation (or sampling, or polling, or gaming, …) results?

I am aware of the RANDU debacle and of

Ferrenberg, A. M., D. P. Landau, and Y. J. Wong. 1992. “Monte Carlo Simulations: Hidden Errors From “Good” Random Number Generators”. Physical Review Letters 69 (23): 3382–3384.

and

Peter Grassberger, "On correlations in 'good' random number generators," Physics Letters A, 181, 1993, 43-46.

and

Bauke, Heiko and Stephan Mertens, "Pseudo Random Coins Show More Heads than Tails," J. Stat. Phys. 114, 1149-1169, (2004)Normand, J.-

Any more? Maybe some that are less specialized?

(I am not looking for successful attempts to break encryption…)

Comment: You are looking for situations where a PRNG which was indistinguishable from a random variable would yield the right result, but a flawed PRNG caused a different result to occur?  And why exclude crypto? Is it because of the existence of an intelligent adversary exploiting weaknesses?

Comment: yes. real-life examples of when a flawed pseudoRNG produced simulation results (or polling results...) that were demonstrably wrong

Comment: It is not easy to prove that a pseudorandom generator does not work properly. You need significant deviations from the expected numbers. Is this the case ?

Comment: In the above cited papers: yes. there are significant deviations